# Match enum item tuples that implement the same trait

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, code-duplication

I have written a [CLI program](https://github.com/DZ-BAM/typesxml/tree/main) using `clap`.

In it, I have several structs and enums containing these structs for the specific sub-commands.

I now ran into the issue of a certain type of code duplication and wonder, whether the Rust language has some feature, that I am unaware of, that can deduplicate this.

Here's a MRE:

```rust
pub trait Runner {
    fn run(&self);
}

pub struct Foo;

impl Runner for Foo {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("Fooing");
    }
}

pub struct Bar;

impl Runner for Bar {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("Baring");
    }
}

pub enum Action {
    DoFoo(Foo),
    DoBar(Bar),
}

impl Runner for Action {
    fn run(&self) {
        match self {
            Self::DoFoo(runner) => runner.run(),
            Self::DoBar(runner) => runner.run(),
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the pattern matching on `<Action as Runner>::run()` has mostly the same code on all variants, since all of the enum variant's tuples contain exactly one element that implements `Runner`.

In this MRE it's quite trivial, but [my actual code](https://github.com/DZ-BAM/typesxml/blob/8e15af538f31771e524bcfe235ae29f0906fc139/src/bin/typesxml/args/action.rs#L30) has currently seven variants.

Is it possible in Rust to deduplicate this pattern matching and use the fact that all variants contain a struct with the same trait?

Comment: Declarative macros are generally used for this sort of deduplication. Although here the trait is completely unnecessary and useless, I don't see anything that's generic over it, it's just overhead.

Comment: It's not code duplication.

Comment: @Masklinn I only added the trait for the slim chance that I could use it in the pattern matching. If that's not possible, the trait is indeed useless.

Comment: pattern matching is for type, a trait is not a type.

Comment: When trying to mimic the dynamic-dispatch approach (relying on `dyn` traits) with enums, the [`enum_dispatch` crate](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) automates the boilerplate for the systematic forwarding of each method in the trait.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is _delegation_. There is nothing builtin in Rust currently supporting this (but there are ideas), but there are third-party crates that can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When trying to mimic the dynamic-dispatch approach (relying on `dyn` traits) with enums, the [`enum_dispatch` crate](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) automates the boilerplate for the systematic forwarding of each method in the trait.

Here is a simple example, based on yours.
`#[enum_dispatch]` is used on the trait you intend to implement for many of your types.
`#[enum_dispatch(Runner)]` instructs the following enum that each of its variants are types that implement this trait, then the forwarding of every trait method is automatically generated for all of these variants, as you would do manually (each method is a `match` statement considering all the variants in order to forward the call on it).

```rust
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;

#[enum_dispatch]
pub trait Runner {
    fn run(&self);
}

pub struct Foo;

impl Runner for Foo {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("Fooing");
    }
}

pub struct Bar;

impl Runner for Bar {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("Baring");
    }
}

#[enum_dispatch(Runner)]
pub enum Action {
    Foo,
    Bar,
}

fn main() {
    let actions = [
        Action::from(Foo {}),
        Action::from(Bar {}),
        Action::from(Bar {}),
        Action::from(Foo {}),
    ];
    for a in actions.iter() {
        a.run();
    }
}
/*
Fooing
Baring
Baring
Fooing
*/
```